# Are there any examples of social animals which show collective behavioral change in response to disease?

Tags: zoology, ethology, behaviour, infectious-diseases

When Covid-19 happened, collective behavioral changes were taken in order to curb the spread of the virus by the human race. Do things like these happen in other animals as well? Like isolating a person who gets sick and such.

Comment: Interesting question. Here we are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. As stated by @JiminyCricket we are expected to demonstrate prior research when posting. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions are subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details and then delete or edit. ——— For example, I did a quick search and came up with [this article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/animals-use-social-distancing-to-avoid-disease1/).